# How to Take output in txt file of java program while executing program using bat file?

Tags: java, batch-file

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WriteToFileExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
    {
        String content = "@ECHO OFF \n javac Hello.java 1> Output.txt 2>Error.txt \n java  Hello 1> Output.txt 2>Error.txt";
        File file = new File("hello.bat");
         // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists())
        {
            file.createNewFile();

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(content);
            bw.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

            String filePath = "hello.bat";
             Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Above code execute below code ahe create `Output.txt` file
containing Output of below program.

```
class Hello
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
     System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

I want solution to run program which take user input

Like

```
import java.io.*;
class Hello
{
      public static void main(String args[])
      {
         System.out.println("Enter String:");
         BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(System.in));
         String s=br.readLine();

         System.out.println(s);
      }
}
```

Please give me solution to get output or any other solution to create Text file of output.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you are trying to achieve? In particular do you want to have command line java program that will get input from stdin and also save its stdout to a text file?

Comment: 1st program compile 2nd program and save Output to text file.  I output of 3rd program and save it in text file.   But i want to give input from text file containing input for program .   when 1st program compile 3rd program it should take input from that text file       You can give me Other solution to create Output text file.

Comment: While running when program ask for input  "Enter String" input should given from txt file automatically and complete execute program and save Output to Output.txt file